# Euler Angle Rotation To Direction Incorrect X Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I am working on this game where the I have a local euler angle that controls where the camera aims. Its horizontal range is 0 - 360 and its vertical range is -88 - 88. I also have a world position vector of a game object that I want that euler angle to aim at.

For the most part in my calculation the euler angle of Y(horizontal) is correct and works perfectly. However the X axis(vertical) works as long as the camera Y axis does not exceed 5.f or go below 5.f.

Here is the calculation

```
Vector2 CalcEuler(Vector3 dst, Vector3 src)
{
    //dst is game object vector position, src is player camera position
    UnityEngine_Quaternion_o quat = UnityEngine_Quaternion_o::LookRotation((dst - src).ToUnityVec3(), UnityEngine_Vector3_o::get_right());
    Vector3 euler = quat.get_eulerAngles();
    return { euler.y, euler.x };
}
```

euler.y returns the correct horizontal rotation flawlessly. However euler.x does return the correct vertical rotation but if the objects position Y is above or below the local camera position it will return numbers higher than max euler Y can support(around 256.f)

ANSWER:

```
while (euler.x >= 88.f)
    euler.x -= 360.f;

while (euler.x <= -88.f)
    euler.x += 360.f;

if (euler.x > 0.6f) {
    euler.x = -euler.x + 0.6f;
}
else if (euler.x < -0.6)
    euler.x = fabsf(euler.x) - 0.6;
```

Comment: yes 360-number  = say 256

Comment: @BugFinder the value returned is usually random but always above 200. Right now I have tried using Vector3.up instead of Vector3.right and its the same result except now itll shoot to 359.99 as max Y if the object is above or below my cameras Y

Comment: a bit confused why you go from a direction to quaternion just to then go back to euler angles .. wouldn't it be easier to just calculate in euler right away?

Comment: @derHugo yes it would but since I am using c++ while interacting with c# code/classes I'm not able to properly allocate or create a new class instance. I'm forced to use static functions.

Comment: `Vector3 euler = quat.get_eulerAngles();` is pretty much allocating a Vector3 anyway though right?

Comment: @derHugo yes that is correct, how would I be able to fix the euler X member? Ive went through countless posts on unity/stack/gamedev exchange and I havent found a solution yet.

Comment: In my experience, euler angles are kind of a pain to work with, in part since there 12 different conventions and you need to know what particular convention your system uses. I find geometric operations, like computing the angle between the look at direction and the 'up direction', easier to get a intuitive understanding of. Other things that can help is unit tests, and displaying vectors, matrices, etc on screen to get some idea what is happening.

Comment: Also, you are using `UnityEngine_Vector3_o::get_right()` as the ' up vector', that seem like an *interesting* choice, and will certainly affect the produced rotation and euler angles.

Comment: @JonasH Vector3.up doesnt work either, nothing does. Pitch is always off by some amount